# Class object - while creating append to a json file

Tags: python, json, class

What is the right and most efficient way of appending newly created object instances to a json file? I need a file as a backup so later it can be used to restore the objects easily. Thanks!

```
import json
class Employee:
def __init__(self, name, salary):
    self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
```

Comment: Not everything can be jsonfied. Check [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Pickling is the right way to serialize Python objects.

Comment: @Shiva well, you can always implement something the `json` module provides various hooks to serialize/deserialize custom objects, you can mange this yourself, although realistically for a large project you would probably just use a library like `pydantic` or `marshmallow`. But yes, probably the OP could just use pickle.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agree. I shouldn't have made such an absolute statement(Pickling is the right way...).